How to select and enter all role names (separate column) in the incoming data field as an array in typeorm query
I have a typeorm library using nestjs and a mysql database which has a table user, user_roles (many to many) and roles. I also have a user who already has the super_admin role.
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  relations: ['roles.role'],
});

The following comes in response:
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "password": "Parol123",
        "created_at": "2024-07-17T10:10:49.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-07-17T10:10:49.000Z",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "role": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "super_admin",
                    "label": "Super Admin",
                    "description": "https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

I need to change the incoming roles value so that it only displays the role name, for example:
roles: ["super_admin"]
I tried using Query Builder, but it didn't work for me either.

Once you get the information need you can use the map function and format the response yourself
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  relations: ['roles.role'],
});
return users.map(user=>{
  return {
    ...user,
    roles: user.roles.map(role=>role.role.name)
  }
})

